# How can integrate Keycloak with kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, keycloak, sasl, keycloak-services

I have configured 3 nodes kafka cluster. Now we want to setup security with Keycloak for kafka. Please let me know what are the ways to do the same.

Question 1: How to implement security for kafka broker to kafka broker with keycloak?

Question 2: How to implement security for kafka client to kafka broker with keycloak?

Note: We had already Keycloak setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure Kafka to use `AUTHBEARER` which is implemented in latest `kafka` release , You can find more info how to configure [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_oauth.html) .

And also get more information about the feature from [Kafka doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=75968876)

You need to implement  `org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.AuthenticateCallbackHandler` to get token from keycloak  and validate token from Keycloak.

Comment: Thanks. OAuthBearer is not generating secure tokens right?. And let's say, if I go with   AuthenticateCallbackHandler for keycloak then which grant_type will use for broker to broker and client to broker communication?

Comment: If i implement keycloak in kafka, then how can I validate token in broker and how can I recreate token if it has expired?

Comment: what is your use case is your broker in unsecured network ? there are different ways , one option is you can use offline tokens , where you need to take care of getting refresh tokens every time.  http://blog.keycloak.org/2015/12/offline-tokens-in-keycloak.html

Comment: Thanks for info. Which SASL mechanism needs to use for kafka with keycloak and how can I pass access_token from client to kafka broker?